# Gmail conversation grouping (threads) causing HTML email format issues

Tags: email, gmail, html-email

I have an HTML email that I send to my users.  It looks great in all major Web, Desktop, and Mobile clients even Gmail, EXCEPT when the email is included as part of a "conversation" in Gmail.  In that case, some of the table background colors don't show, the text alignment is wrong, etc.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Following.  I need to do this without changing the sender or the subject line.  As far as I can tell, the threading is based on 1. the sender, and 2. the subject line.  I've tried inserting HTML spaces, <br></br> tags, and invisible HTML characters into these areas with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your messages have different subject lines, that'll prevent them from being in a conversation. Or, if just testing, leave the subject line blank.

Comment: Yeah, I added a timestamp to the subject and to the very bottom of the email message (to prevent the "Download Entire Message" prompt).  I was hoping there was something more elegant, but alas there is not :-(

Answer (score 1):

Tested answer: Change the sender of your email by inserting a random number.  So instead of sending from foo@bar.com, send from foo+1@bar.com.  Functionally, these are the same email address (replying will send to the same person).

In ES5:

```js
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*100).toString();
from = 'Foo <foo+' + randomNumber + '@bar.com>';
```

In ES6:

```js
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
from = `My Company <foo+${randomNumber}@bar.com>`;
```

Comment: This doesnt work . 2022